# Unity3D - Failed to Build APK on Samsung Galaxy tab GT-P3110

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

When I debug and Run game from unity3D to samsung galaxy tab **GT-P3110**, Unity Gives Error saying

> Installation failed with the following output:
>       pkg: /data/local/tmp/Package.apk
>
> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE]
>
> 3208 KB/s (39633370 bytes in 12.062s)
>
> UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

I have checked USB debugging in Developer options, Connected this device through **Samsung Kies** and in **CMD** by typing

> C:/> adb

all go well but at the end, build fails.

*With these settings all went correct in Huawei honor 3C*

Comment: Not sure if this qualifies as an exact duplicate, but the error message indicates that your device's storage is full. See previous questions on this topic: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815625/failure-install-failed-media-unavailable), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273526/installation-error-install-failed-media-unavailable).